# Please Explain Ping -R www.xyz.com in a specific case?

Tags: unix

When I use this command on unix :

$ping -R intra.mycompany.com (intranet address of my company)

It gives me all the desired router information (when I ping for local intranet address.)

but when I use this for some other web site (outside intranet i.e. on internet) I get this :-

$ ping -R www.stackoverflow.com

PING www.sta.com (64.34.119.12) 56(124) bytes of data.
From 10.203.129.242 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable

Could someone explain the behavior of ping in above scenario.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I think this means you are unable to ping stackoverflow.com or outside internet sites for whatever reason.

[This](http://www.corenetworkz.com/2009/05/destination-host-unreachable-reason-and.html) might be helpful information as it details the issue and possible solutions.

BTW: I know the link shows a windows cmd prompt but (without knowing unix) I guess the issues would be similar on Windows and Unix, as I think its a network connection issue.

Hope this is helpful, if not sorry!

Comment: thanks for help....I already googled for "Destination Host Unreachable:ping" error and got some idea,but didn't get the right solution....

Comment: @Sandeep - no problem. Good Luck finding your answer